# react native Flatlist not rendering and my code is clean

Tags: react-native, expo

i am writing perfect code but its not rendering

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View,  StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList } from "react-native";
import AppCard from "../components/AppCard";
import { Avatar, Button, Card, Text } from "react-native-paper";

function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
        setData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card>
            <Card.Cover source={{ uri: item.image }} />
            <Card.Content style={{ margin: 19 }}>
              <Text variant="titleLarge">{item.title}</Text>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default Home;
```

i wrote a clean code but its not working at all

llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

Comment: Try to give your View and FlatList component the ```flex: 1``` style

Comment: I think `keyExtractor` is missing

Answer (score 1):

In your useEffect, you are setting the fetched data directly to the data state variable. However, you should set the actual data from the API response, which is typically found in the data property of the response object. To fix this, you should change setData(data) to setData(data.data):

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Image, StyleSheet,Text, ScrollView, FlatList, Alert } from "react-native";


function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products",{
          method:"GET"
        }).then((data) => data.json()).then((data) => {
          setData(data)
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          Alert.alert("ERROR", JSON.stringify(err)
          )
        })
       
      } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert("ERROR", JSON.stringify(error))
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{margin:20, backgroundColor:"red"}}>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} />
            <View style={{ margin: 19 }}>
              <Text variant="titleLarge">{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default Home;
```